# Inner join in ruby on rails 4

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, join

I encountered "**undefined method 'join**'" error when I try to display all the clubnames that the current user requested.

In my controller:

```
@clubs = Club.find(:conditions=> ["Request.userid = session[:userid]"],
                                     :joins=>[:Request])
```

In my view:

```
@clubs.each do |c| 
  c.clubname
end
```

The equivalent query that I wish to load is

```
SELECT clubname FROM clubs 
INNER JOIN request 
ON request.clubid = clubs.clubid 
WHERE request.userid = session[:userid]
```

Been modifying my code from various sources but doesnt seem working... The sources that I have been trying out are: [railsforum](http://archive.railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=16752) and [dsone](http://dzone.com/snippets/rails-inner-joins-association) but they don't seem to work in my code.

Answer (score 2):

One way to get what you're looking for would be:

```
@clubs.joins(:request).where(request: { userid: session[:userid] })
```

**UPDATE:** The doesn't seem to be working for the OP, most likely because as @vee pointed out, the table is singular. If that's the case, it'll need to be a bit less pretty:

```
@clubs.joins('request').where('request.user_id = ?', session[:userid])
```

Comment: I just updated the answer, hopefully that helps. If not, could you paste the full error log in your question please?

Answer (score 1):

Your use of conditions suggests that `Request` is a database table in mysql.  That table name is usually and according to Rails, pluralized and lowercased.  Try:

```
@clubs = Club.find(:conditions=> ["requests.userid = ?", session[:userid]], :joins=>[:Request])
```

I'm unsure why your `:Request` is capitalized in `joins`, that also I believe by convention is supposed to be `:request`.

The second problem is the use of `"requests.userid = session[:userid]"`.  Note that the `session[:userid]` is not going to be interpolated here.  As suggested you should be using parameterized query as updated in the code snippet above.

And you already have another answer by @JKen13579 here which looks much better syntactically!